# Hardware enablement stack install is giving dependency issues

Tags: 12.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm trying to install the hardware enablement stack onto 12.04 but I'm running into the following dependency issue:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1 is to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-trusty: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed
```

How can I circumvent this and get the HWE to install?

Comment: This is weird. The dependencies are met, but `apt` is refusing to install the packages. If you have `aptitude`, can you try installing it through `aptitude` so that we can get more descriptive error messages?

Comment: [Bug #1328264 - packaging issues with the trusty Xstack in precise xserver-xorg-lts-trusty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error messages when I tried to update my 12.04 with kernel 3.5.0-48-generic. Since the dependency that was not being met was libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty I tried to install it manually and got this error:

libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty:
Conflicts: libglapi-mesa
Conflicts: libglapi-mesa

So I used synaptic to remove libglapi-mesa and then entered the following on a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`

And that successfully updated my system to kernel 3.13.0-30-generic. After rebooting got a message that said that my hardware enablement stack was now supported till 2017.

Hope this helps.