# Failed to upgrade new hardware support for Ubuntu 12.04 - unmet dependencies libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty etc

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

Ubuntu update manager offers me new hardware support. When I try to upgrade I get the following error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1 is to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
libglu1-mesa-dev: Depends: libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7 is to be installed
libqt4-opengl-dev: Depends: libqt4-dev (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
libvtk5-dev: Depends: libvtk5.8 (= 5.8.0-5) but 5.8.0-5 is to be installed
             Depends: libexpat-dev but it is a virtual package
             Depends: libpng-dev but it is a virtual package
             Depends: libtiff-dev but it is a virtual package
xserver-xorg-core-lts-saucy: Depends: xserver-common-lts-saucy (>= 2:1.14.6-0ubuntu1~precise2) but 2:1.14.6-0ubuntu1~precise2 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-trusty: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed
```

Does anybody has an idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: From which command did the quoted output result?

Comment: It's from the GUI tool 'Update Manager'.

Comment: [Bug #1328264 - packaging issues with the trusty Xstack in precise xserver-xorg-lts-trusty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a packaging bug - [bug #1328264 - packaging issues with the trusty Xstack in precise xserver-xorg-lts-trusty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264). The commands to workaround it are:

**amd64:**

```
apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386 libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty
```

**i386:**

```
apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty
```

[Another potential solution:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498482/hardware-enablement-stack-install-is-giving-dependency-issues#498536)

> I used synaptic to remove libglapi-mesa and then entered the following
>   on a terminal window:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty
> ```
>
> And that successfully updated my system to kernel 3.13.0-30-generic.
>   After rebooting got a message that said that my hardware enablement
>   stack was now supported till 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but the packages could not be installed. The error message is like the one in my original post.

Comment: @Mathias Did you try removing libglapi-mesa?

Comment: How it is possible to remove just _libglapi-mesa_ by synaptic? If I try that, synaptic wants to remove the whole xserver!

Comment: I think that is the point - uninstall the old xserver, then install the new one.

Comment: I removed libglapi-mesa by synaptic. If I try to install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty I get unmet dependencies too.

Comment: Try removing `xserver*saucy` and/or installing xserver-xorg-lts-precise. From the bug report _"Only installing the original precice Xstack (xserver-xorg-lts-precise), which removes the current xstack and after that installing the trusty xstack"_

Comment: I donÄ't know how and I don't understand why but it seems that after several updates the problem is solved. Thank you very much.